# set a animation for several view and start one after another

Tags: android

I want to set a animation for several View.and start One after another(such below imag)
[image]

I create a translation:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
 <translate 

         android:fromXDelta="-6%p" android:toXDelta="50%p"
         android:duration="2000"/>
```

and set for Views.

```
    imag1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imag_icon1);
    imag2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imag_icon2);
    imag3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imag_icon3)        
    anim1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.several_anim);
 int count=0;
 ImageView [] arr_imag={imag1,imag2,imag3};
 arr_imag[count].startAnimation(anim1);

    anim1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            count++;
     if(count<3)
        arr_imag[count].startAnimation(anim1);

                }


    });
```

but when run app .
start Animation with together.
I'm really confused.
What is the problem

Comment: try to create seperate animation objects for seperate view and on end of first animation object, start second animation object

Comment: I create Animation anim2,anim3;   anim2=anim3=anim1;but There is still a problem

Comment: do like this- `anim1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.several_anim);` `anim2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.several_anim);` not like anim1=anim2=anim3...and also sepearte `setAnimationlistener`

Comment: Is this logical?
There is a better way?

Comment: because you are using same object for animation thats why your animation for all views works simultaneously... if there is seperate object then they will not run at same time

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

anim1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromXDelta="-6%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
 </set>
```

anim2.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromXDelta="-6%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
 </set>
```

anim3.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromXDelta="-6%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
 </set>
```

then use this

```
    Animation animanim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim1);
    Animation animanim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim2);
    Animation animanim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim3);
    imag1.startAnimation(animanim1);
    imag2.startAnimation(animanim2);
    imag3.startAnimation(animanim3);
```